# Transparency Face-Jumping?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I've been working on a WebGL project that runs on top of the Three.js library. I am rendering several semi-transparent meshes, and I notice that depending on the angle you tilt the camera, a different object is on top.

To illustrate the problem, I made a quick demo using three semi-transparent cubes. When you rotate the image past perpendicular to the screen, the second half of the smallest cube "jumps" and is no longer visible. However, shouldn't it still be visible? I tried adjusting some of the blending equations, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

What I'm wondering is whether or not this is a bug in WebGL/Three, or something I can fix. Any insight would be much appreciated :)

Comment: It looks like the nested models are culled by the depth test. Try to call `gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)` before drawing any transparent models if it jumps or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, that's something they weren't able to solve when they invented all this hardware accelerated graphics business and sounds like we'll have to deal with this for a long while.

The issue here is that graphic cards do not sort the polygons, nor objects. The graphics card is "dumb", you tell it to draw an object and it will draw the pixels that represent it and also, in another non-visible "image" called zbuffer (or depthbuffer), will draw the pixels that represent the object but instead of color it will draw the distance to the camera for each pixels. Any other objects that you draw afterwards, the graphics card will check if the distance to the camera for each pixel, and if it's farther, it won't draw it (unless you disable the check, that is).

This speeds up things a lot and gives you nice intersections between solid objects. But it doesn't play well with transparency. Say that you have 2 transparent objects and you want A to be drawn behind B. You'll need to tell the graphics card to draw A first and then B. This works fine as long as they're not intersecting. In order to draw 2 transparent objects intersecting then the graphics would have to sort all the polygons, and as the graphics card doesn't do that, then you'll have to do it.

It's one of these things that you need to understand and specifically tweak for your case.

In three.js, if you set `material.transparent = true` we'll sort that object so it's drawn before (earlier) other objects that are in front. But we can't really help you if you want to intersect them.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. I modified an existing jsFiddle from WestLangley that demonstrates the problem for anyone who's interested: http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/2LnCj/2/