# Three.js: Using cubeMaterials and opacity with MeshFaceMaterial - THREE.DoubleSide not working?

Tags: html, three.js, html5-canvas

I am using ThreeJS r65 to create a simple cube. The opposite faces of the cube have same colors assigned:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000); 
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0); // bg color
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); // displays canvas

camera.position.z = 13; // move away to see coord center
camera.position.y = 7;

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// CUBE
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(2,2,2);
var cubeMaterials = [ 
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x33AA55, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x55CC00, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide}), 
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x000000, transparent:true, opacity:0.2, side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xFF0000, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide}), 
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xFF0000, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide}), 
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x5555AA, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide}), 
]; 
// Create a MeshFaceMaterial, which allows the cube to have different materials on each face 
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(cubeMaterials); 
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, cubeMaterial);
scene.add( cube );

var render = function () { 
    requestAnimationFrame(render); 
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 
};

render();
```

If you look from top into the cube, you see that only the first two **green** faces show their color inside. The other 4 faces only show the color from outside but not from inside. See also image:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Or is it due to WebGL?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221328/artifacts-when-rendering-both-sides-of-a-transparent-object-with-three-js. Try rendering 6 separate plane objects and then repost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change your material with this colors......
http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/rp7NU/

```
var cubeMaterials = [ 
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide}), 
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x0000ff, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffff00, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide}), 
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff00ff, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide}), 
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ffff, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide})];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't it the same code? Do I miss something? Why is it working with those intense colors and the colors I am using don't work?

Comment: its because of Color depth.... Red color has more depth so u cant see inside over that face it, even u apply the opacity(0.8)... Just understand colors and its nature.. For code u can check the fiddle link.... If the answer useful... please dont forget to accept the answer..