# Render a realistic transparent bottle with three.js

Tags: three.js

How to render a realistic, transparent, glass bottle that has a label, and is partially filled with liquid?

My attempt did not turn out well :(

My example: http://neftek.legko.ufanet.ru/MyWebGL/xim/

Comment: You probably need to use raytracing, instead. With three.js `WebGLRenderer`, however, you can start by adding an environment map, reflection, and refraction.  Also search this site for issues related to [self-transparency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221328/artifacts-when-rendering-both-sides-of-a-transparent-object-with-three-js/13236863#13236863).