# Self-transparency issue in CylinderGeometry of THREE.js

Tags: three.js, transparency

I tried to draw a cylinder with MeshLambertMaterial in THREE.js, and rotate it with TrackballControl.js, but found half of the cylinder is not transparent. When rotate to some angle, the opaque half will shade the transparent half, which looks like

The essential code is

```
c = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5, 5, 20, 25 );

m = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    color:0xaaaaaa,
    opacity: 0.6,
    transparent: true,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
} ); 

scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( c, m ) );
```

I googled similar issue, and some people says that it's the nature of OpenGL and graphic card. I just want to confirm that is there no way to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221328/artifacts-when-rendering-both-sides-of-a-transparent-object-with-three-js/13236863#13236863