# I use three.js to make a Transparent earth，but get some strange result

Tags: three.js

I use three.js to make a Transparent earth，but get some strange result，I tried depthTest、depthWrite and so on, but not get the right result。

picture shown below:

sphere bottom looks strange

[image: [image1]

looks right in some angle

[image: image2]

green is background color, material parameters like this:

```
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: child.material.map, transparent: true, opacity: 0.6, side:THREE.DoubleSide}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221328/artifacts-when-rendering-both-sides-of-a-transparent-object-with-three-js/13236863#13236863

Comment: Thanks WestLangley,This can temporarily solve this problem.