# three.js transparency renderring anomaly

Tags: three.js

History:
Working on Clara.io anatomy models exported from Mathematica

https://forum.clara.io/t/transparency-artifact/6421
https://clara.io/player/v2/588449a8-1370-4433-8b30-544e34dba272?wait=true

Some anomalies observed when surfaces are enclosing volumes or overlapping certain ways.

In most cases it does not
https://clara.io/player/v2/1e0c3009-dabc-4d0c-af91-8dec5b851263?wait=true

Mostly happens when the surfaces bound a volume
https://clara.io/player/v2/4d432c4e-2b0e-4c9c-9fee-18ff8517d6f8?wait=true

Problem occurs also in OPENGL and Sketchfab
https://sketchfab.com/models/d7542d0179064a208a1c952dba028376

Three.js folks told me to post here

Dara

Comment: For a possible workaround, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221328/artifacts-when-rendering-both-sides-of-a-transparent-object-with-three-js/13236863#13236863).

Comment: Thank you West, do not know how and where  to apply this past solution to a similar bug. We host with Clara and therefore need a clear statement to them so they could start looking into the problem.

Comment: It is not a bug; it is how webgl works. Other solutions are to sort the transparent faces from back to front prior to rendering, which can be prohibitive, or implement a form of order-independent-transparency in your shaders.

Comment: see this https://clara.io/player/v2/1e0c3009-dabc-4d0c-af91-8dec5b851263?wait=true which works and then see https://clara.io/player/v2/4d432c4e-2b0e-4c9c-9fee-18ff8517d6f8?wait=true  which has the anomaly. Former is 2 sheet surfaces, latter is 1 closed surface . If your assertion was correct the both should show the same anomaly