# Object is not fully transparent

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I want to apply opacity on my object, when I set transparent to true and opacity, the object becomes mostly transparent, I can still see some faces where the front and back side are overlapping.

[image: photo_example]

With the options `side: THREE.DoubleSide` is even worst.
I have tried to combine those two options, but without success:
`combine = THREE.MixOperation;` and `depthWrite = true;`

```
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5,
});
```

Comment: have you tried setting the opacity to 0 instead of 0.5?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221328/artifacts-when-rendering-both-sides-of-a-transparent-object-with-three-js/13236863#13236863) is your issue.

Comment: I would say it is a problem with the cleanliness of your mesh. Modelling for three.js is the same as for games, the cleaner your mesh (quads rather than tris or ngons and no overlapping verticies) the better your results will be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [artifacts when rendering both sides of a transparent object with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221328/artifacts-when-rendering-both-sides-of-a-transparent-object-with-three-js)

Comment: I have tried @WestLangley suggestion, but without success.

Comment: Can be what @2pha commented, but for that should also be a solution.

Comment: If it is a mesh cleanliness issue, then the solution is to clean up the mesh in a modelling program. If you post a link to the model, then we could have a look.