# What's the simplest way to render overlapping transparent meshes in THREE.js?

Tags: three.js, 3d, webgl

I'd like to render transparent surfaces that partially overlap in THREE.js. I am not looking for perfect rendering of multiple overlapping surface, but would just like something that looks a little better than the current result - where for example if I have two ellipsoids, the one whose centre is behind gets rendered all with reference to that depth, even if parts of its surface are effectively in front of the other. I should also mention I'm using OrbitControls, so I can't simply order them statically once and forget about them.

I've seen that Depth Peeling is usually the technique for this, and even found someone who wrote an example doing it in THREE.js. Unfortunately it also looks rather complicated and possibly performance heavy. I was wondering if there were simpler alternatives. Something I've considered is just splitting each mesh in its fundamental triangles and pushing each as a separate geometry, but I don't know how much of a performance hit that would cause, and it would make all further rescaling/rotating operations messier. I saw that THREE's BufferGeometry class has an option for 'groups' that will be drawn in separate calls, but that alone doesn't seem to fix it. Is there anything else you think I could do? Maybe using a custom shader? Or should I really go with Depth Peeling?

Comment: If you know make shader custom. Please post you attempt ( source code ) if you wanna help from somebody. Q is not 100% clear .

Comment: I haven't tried anything specific yet. I was asking for possible ideas, whether this could be done with a shader, I didn't mean I tried doing it already.

Comment: how many triangles total? Putting each one on a separate Mesh you just parent them to a Group and move the group. I'd guess 1000-2000 max before your perf is too low.

Comment: @Okarin Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947704/rendering-a-transparent-shell

Comment: @Okarin Alternatively, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221328/artifacts-when-rendering-both-sides-of-a-transparent-object-with-three-js/13236863#13236863

Comment: @gman I tried that. Still, if I put them in a group, they all act as a single object compared with other groups. On the other hand if I put all objects in a group I can't apply individual scale and rotation transforms. Which then becomes complicated to handle for a different reason.

Comment: Screen door transparency can be used to alleviate some of the transparency overlap problems. It comes with its own artifacts (limited transparency overlap, visible pixel patterns) but maybe it's workable for you. With different anti aliasing technique the screen door artifacts are actually less notice-able. I've implemented this in THREE before but I don't have it available online at the moment -- I can try to provide an answer later if it's of interest. Here's some more information: https://digitalrune.github.io/DigitalRune-Documentation/html/fa431d48-b457-4c70-a590-d44b0840ab1e.htm

Comment: Thanks @GarrettJohnson! That looks indeed a great idea, and so simple I'm now slapping my forehead for not thinking of it! It would probably suit my application just fine, I don't need anything exceedingly pretty or naturalistic, it just needs to convey information efficiently.

Comment: Update: unfortunately the most basic form of screen door transparency I tried suffers from the same problems as the simple alpha blending - it makes sense since anyway it's about rendering 'transparent' textures. This right now I'm trying by setting the alpha channel in the fragment shader. Maybe there are other alternatives.

Comment: Update 2: it works if instead of simply setting the alpha to 0 I outright discard the fragment! Now I only need to blend this with the rest of the shader, and find a way to add some kind of 'offset' for other surfaces so that they are visible one through the other. Thanks!

Comment: @Okarin yeah texture opacity needs to be included and the `discard;` operation needs to be used to ensure that depth is not written. I've added an answer with a bit more detail

Comment: FWIW.  For others who might have a similar issue, I ran into the dithering issue with flat overlapping transparent surfaces that were in motion.  Used a combination of offsetting the flat surfaces in the Z direction (as the meshes were in the XY plane) and staggering the mesh renderOrder.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136336 for the details.  Obviously a unique use case, but this tidbit might be useful to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

[Screendoor transparency](https://digitalrune.github.io/DigitalRune-Documentation/html/fa431d48-b457-4c70-a590-d44b0840ab1e.htm) can be used to create stable transparency overlap across frames but comes with a few artifacts that may be undesireable. This gist of the technique is to discard pixels in a screen space pattern depending on how opaque the object is supposed to be. The pattern can be derived from a texture or generated in the shader. The fragments that *aren't* discarded still write to depth and no alpha blending is used.

Here's a bit of code to get started.

Generating a DataTexture with the dither pattern:

```
const data = new Float32Array(16);
data[0] = 1.0 / 17.0;
data[1] = 9.0 / 17.0;
data[2] = 3.0 / 17.0;
data[3] = 11.0 / 17.0;

data[4] = 13.0 / 17.0;
data[5] = 5.0 / 17.0;
data[6] = 15.0 / 17.0;
data[7] = 7.0 / 17.0;

data[8] = 4.0 / 17.0;
data[9] = 12.0 / 17.0;
data[10] = 2.0 / 17.0;
data[11] = 10.0 / 17.0;

data[12] = 16.0 / 17.0;
data[13] = 8.0 / 17.0;
data[14] = 14.0 / 17.0;
data[15] = 6.0 / 17.0;

ditherTex = new THREE.DataTexture(data, 4, 4, THREE.LuminanceFormat, THREE.FloatType);
ditherTex.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
ditherTex.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
ditherTex.anisotropy = 1;
ditherTex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
ditherTex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
```

And some shader code to discard the fragments by:

```
// ...
uniform sampler2D ditherTex;    
void main() {

    // ...

    // get the color of the surface and discard pixels based on the dither pattern       
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(diffuseTex, vUv);
    vec4 color = texColor * vec4(color.rgb, opacity);

    if(texture2D(ditherTex, gl_FragCoord.xy / 4.0).r > color.a) discard;

    // ...

}
```

You'll want to set the data texture to the `ditherTex` uniform used in the shader. You can use a different texture, as well, if you want to use something stylized or less regular.

Lastly some things to keep in mind:

- Texture opacity should be used when comparing to the dither texture.
- The screen door artifacts can be mitigated with some antialiasing approaches to blend surrounding pixels.
- `Material.transparent` should be `false`.
- Because fragments are not blended objects with the same opacity will not show visible overlap.

Hopefully that helps! Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can only add that I actually found this algorithm:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_dithering

that should allow to generate masks of arbitrary power-of-two size for this shader. Though the formula on Wikipedia seems to have some coefficients wrong (I didn't edit it because I wasn't sure, but once tested I may do it).