# Why transparency doesn't work on my mesh?

Tags: three.js, textures

I have two meshes on my scene. One cylinder and one classic plane in the middle. 
I applied a png texture on my cylinder so we can see through. It seems to work for the cylinder.

On this screenshot you'll easily see my issue : I don't understand why my image is not visible behind my cylinder.

[image]

The code I used for my cylinder :

```
myCylinderMesh.material.transparent = true;
myCylinderMesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

How can I manage to see the part of the image hidden behind the cylinder ?

**EDIT 1 :**

I added the code that @ScieCode sent me :

```
myCylinderMesh.material.alphaTest = 0.5;
```

Here's the result : 
[image]

It works better : now I can see the part missing of my image. But there's one thing missing : the opacity of my cylinder. I'm supposed to see my image behind the letters too. 
Currently I have this opacity :

```
myCylinderMesh.material.opacity = 0.7;
```

Do you know what I am missing ? Thanks

**EDIT 2 :**

Here's the code for my two meshes :

Cylinder :

```
geoCylinder = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry( 0.4, 0.4, 2*Math.PI*0.4/(2048/128), 64, 1, true ); 

matCylinder = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:texture, transparent:true, color:0x000000, alphaTest: 0.5, opacity: 0.6, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );

meshCylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geoCylinder, matCylinder );
```

Plane :

```
geoPlane = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 0.8, 0.8 );

matPlane = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texturePlane, transparent:true} );

meshPlane = new THREE.Mesh( geoPlane, matPlane );
```

Comment: Try `material.alphaTest = 0.5;`

Comment: @ScieCode thanks for the answer. I tried it and edit my post. It's almost perfect but the opacity of my letters is still missing.

Comment: Letters look transparent to me, maybe try lowering it? Just make sure to adjust your `alphaTest` so it isn't bigger than your opacity, otherwise nothing will render. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyxr26Lm/)

Comment: @ScieCode it works on your JSFiddle and between the letters of my cylinder but it's not working on my pullover (even when I'm play with the alphaTest and the opacity values). Is it because I'm calling a texture on my plane geometry ? Thank you

Comment: Not really. It's kinda hard to debug without seeing some code, but try setting `depthWrite = false` on your cylinder material. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ex4tqm1L/)

Comment: If this doesn't work, edit your post to include code of you material instantiation, for both meshes please.

Comment: I try your attribute but it didn't work. The post is updated.

Comment: Remove `transparent: true` from your plane material and use `alphaTest` instead, this should fix the issue. Also, consider using `depthWrite = false` on the cylinder, as it removes a few artifacts of self transparency. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjbpgy91/)

Comment: @ScieCode Please formulate your suggestions into an answer for Michaël Garcia to accept.

Comment: @MichaëlGarcia Have look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13236863/1461008) and study the fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior happens because of how transparency rendering works internally. Transparent objects need to be sorted/rendered separately from opaque objects. This assures that objects will render as expected on the final image. (not always, though)

The problem here is that your plane geometry is inside the cylinder geometry, when sorting it will either be rendered first or later. Which, in turn, causes these artifacts you are experiencing here. The whole transparency render is a lot more complex than what I'm making it to be.

Since your plane object doesn't need to be translucent, you can simply set the `alphaTest` property of its material. Which will only render the fragment pixels with alpha greater than this value. This will also prevent that object from being considered transparent and it will always be rendered first, fixing the artifacts in your scene.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2x0ez84/)

**Additional info**: When using a transparent material with `DoubleSide`, you might experience self transparency problems. This happens for the same reason I just explained, but between faces of the same object. A possible solution for this problem is to set `depthWrite = false`, this prevent the object from writing to the depth buffer. So every face will get rendered, disregarding if another face occludes it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I noticed I have the same render than on your JSFiddle, the edge of the image in the middle seems damaged. Do you know how to prevent this behaviour ? Thanks

Comment: That is something directly related with `alphaTest`. Since fragments with alpha values lower than `alphaTest` are discarded, you might experience some problems with sharp edges. Testing different alphaTest values is probably your best bet. Also, this is heavily dependent on the texture used