# Three.js - DoubleSided Semi-Transparent Materials Only Work From Certain Angles

Tags: three.js, camera, transparency, angle

I am currently using three.js and trying to create a 3D experience with a semi-transparent material that can be viewed from all angles. I've noticed that depending on the camera angle, only certain portions of the mesh are semi-transparent and will show the content behind them. In this example below I've created two half cylinders and applied the same transparent material with the stack overflow logo. The half cylinder on the left properly shows the logo on the closest surface, as well as the surface behind it. The half cylinder on the right only shows the logo on the closest surface and fails to render the logo that wraps behind it. However, it does properly render the background image so the material is still treated correctly as transparent:
[image: semi-transparent example]

If I spin the orbital camera around 180 degrees the side that originally failed to see through now works and the other side exhibits the wrong behavior. This leads me to believe it's related to the camera position / depth sorting. The material in this case is a standard MeshPhongMaterial with transparent set to true, side as DoubleSide, and a single map for the transparent stack overflow logo. The geometry is formed from an opened ended CylinderGeometry. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Likely a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221328/artifacts-when-rendering-both-sides-of-a-transparent-object-with-three-js. Or, just try `material.depthWrite = false`.