# Opacity is not being applied to some faces in IconsaHedron in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I tried to make a transparent iconsahedron with Three.js

```
 const plasticMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        transparent: true,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        opacity: 0.5
    });
```

But it looks like that the opacity is not being applied to some faces.
Why does this happen?
This is a screenshot video link.
https://youtu.be/nWa9yc1p9yQ

Thank you.

Comment: It should look better if you do this: `plasticMaterial.depthWrite = false;`.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer did not solve my issue. I could solve it after reading the above post [artifacts when rendering both sides of a transparent object with three.js ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221328/artifacts-when-rendering-both-sides-of-a-transparent-object-with-three-js).